# In ActiveJob, how to catch any exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activejob

The [ActiveJob docs for exception handling](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#exceptions) provide this example for how to perform exception handling within the context of a job:

```
class GuestsCleanupJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  rescue_from(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound) do |exception|
   # Do something with the exception
  end

  def perform
    # Do something later
  end
end
```

I am using this technique in an application I am building and capturing certain particular exceptions. My question is, how to capture any and all exceptions?

I am capturing various kinds of exceptions and performing the same procedure each way, so I would like to DRY up my code and also, in my current implementation, certain exceptions are being ignored which means in some cases my job fails silently.

How do I capture any generic exception using ActiveJob?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this

```
class GuestsCleanupJob < ActiveJob::Base
  ...

  rescue_from(StandardError) do |exception|
   # Do something with the exception
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the proper technique! In my case, there was a failing expression in the exception handling block itself which caused the silent error

Comment: Am missing something, this is not working with Rails 5.2.1 for me